# Getting noise when playing sound windows phone 7 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio

I have a .wav music file.
When I tried to play using SoundEffect.Play();

mus1.Play(); I am getting noise rather than music.
The same is played well in PCs music player.
How to resolve this issue?

How to make sure that it will play good in Windows Phone 7 too?

Comment: Could you post some code to let us know what you tried?

Comment: Francly, this seems to be an issue with the emulator... can't you get someone to test your app and see what the problem is? If you like, you can just post a sample XAP over the internet, me or another dev will sure to help you test and check if the problem persists in a phisical device!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there's content in the .wav file that WP7 doesn't understand. Why don't you try converting it to .wav (yes I know it's already in .wav) as this may remove the unknown data.

Audacity (http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is free and will do this for you. Just drag the .wav file into it and click file --> export...

Comment: I'm sorry to re-ignite an old post, but I am getting the same thing, however simply changing to .WAV with Audacity does not fix it for me, could you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157992/audio-distored-and-incomprehensible-using-windows-phone-mediaelement (I get distortion instead of vocal audio on the actual device)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Code

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace MediaSample
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            progress.DataContext = this;
            this.Loaded += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
            mediaplayer.BufferingProgressChanged += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(mediaplayer_BufferingProgressChanged);
            mediaplayer.CurrentStateChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(mediaplayer_CurrentStateChanged);
        }

        public double Duration { get; set; }

        void mediaplayer_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mediaplayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
            {
                Duration = mediaplayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Progress = mediaplayer.Position.TotalSeconds * 100 / Duration));
                        Thread.Sleep(0);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        void mediaplayer_BufferingProgressChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaElement mediaplayer = sender as MediaElement;
            if (mediaplayer.BufferingProgress == 1)
                Debug.WriteLine(mediaplayer.NaturalDuration);
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mediaplayer.Source = new Uri("/Oru nalum..mp3", UriKind.Relative);
            mediaplayer.Play();
        }



        public double Progress
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ProgressProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ProgressProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Progress.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ProgressProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Progress", typeof(double), typeof(PhoneApplicationPage), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));



    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="MediaSample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Media Application" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>        

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <MediaElement x:Name="mediaplayer"/>
            <ProgressBar Height="40"  x:Name="progress" Value="{Binding Path=Progress}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>


</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Add Mp3 file as follows,
[image]

Like that you can add .wav files. Working good. Tested codes above.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use MeadiaElement Rather than using SoundEffect Class. 
try this one
[MediaElement](http://www.michaelsnow.com/2010/12/17/playing-sound-effects-on-windows-phone-7/)