# Audio distored and incomprehensible using Windows Phone MediaElement?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, audio

Incredibly strange one this evening, I am attempting to play an audio snippet in my Windows Phone game (Silverlight, not XNA), and the MP3 in question plays completely fine and clear through Windows Media Player or VLC, yet when I use the `MediaElement` (Silverlight) or `Song` or `SoundEffect` even using XNA it is garbled, quiet and incomprehensible? What could be the cause of this?

I even tried re-saving it with Adobe Audition using a different bitrate, and a bunch of other variations, but to no avail.

Here is the culprit MP3 in question: http://goneale.com/files/SO/YouDidIt.mp3

If you could try using my mp3 with below code snippet and could determine what might be going on, that would be fantastic!

```
SoundTrigger.Source = new Uri("YouDidIt.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
SoundTrigger.Play();
```

then on the XAML surface:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="SoundTrigger" />
```

If it helps, this vocal snippet was recorded at home with Garage Band for mac.

Something astonishing, and I just cannot believe it, is if I take a snippet of a music mp3 and insert it directly in the middle, the start of my voice on the mp3 is garbled, then the half second of perfect music plays, then resumes the garbled voice, how could this be?!

**Update 2012-11-1: Ok, new very strange finding, when I plug the headphones into my Lumia 710 the sound plays perfectly fine?! But not through the speaker? The speaker is just hiss with a distored voice in the distance, this is a brand new phone, not even 2 weeks old, as I said it plays everything else perfectly fine and crystal clear. What could be going on?**

Comment: Try saving the original file (from GarageBand) into `WAV` format and see if it plays fine. If so, it may be an encoder setting from GarageBand. If that WAV plays fine, try then encoding the `WAV` file to MP3 with `Audacity`.

Comment: Ok will try that, did try .aif with no luck the other day though.. Will try .wav!

Comment: No luck with .wav, tried a bunch of others using Audacity too :( Anyone able to try with a test project for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it!

It was all because I was using a balanced Shure SM-58 microphone straight into an unbalanced input and recording in stereo or something when it should have been mono for my phone.

That explains why it came through correctly when I plugged my headphones in but not through my phone's speaker output.

I can't remember the link I had which explained how to fix this, but basically if you have a recording faulting like this, in Audacity click the little drop down arrow in the track and press "Split Stereo To Mono", then you will get two tracks, highlight one, then File -> Export Selection. Works a treat!

See here for more information on the menu: http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Splitting_and_Joining_Stereo_Tracks